# SqlDataReader displaying like fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

When I try to display only distinct values in my DB with `SqlDataReader`, it is still showing duplicate columns.

```
string State = ddlState.SelectedItem.Value;
string City = ddlCities.SelectedItem.Text;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=--myDB--;Database=--MyconnectionString--");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select distinct State, City, ExchangeType, Boid, Bex, Npa, Nxx from TAS where StateId=" + "'" + State + "'" + " AND City=" + "'" + City + "'", con);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlCities.SelectedItem.Text))
{
    exchangesheet.Visible = true;

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        this.STATE.Text = rdr["State"].ToString();
        this.CITY.Text = rdr["City"].ToString();
        this.ExchangeType.Text = rdr["ExchangeType"].ToString();
        this.BOID.Text += rdr["Boid"].ToString() + ", ";
        this.BEX.Text += rdr["Bex"].ToString() + ", ";
        this.NPA.Text += rdr["Npa"].ToString() + ", ";
        this.NXX.Text += rdr["Nxx"].ToString() + ", ";
    }

    con.Close();
}
else
{
    exchangesheet.Visible = false;
}
```

All queries with `+=` are resulting in duplicate data in the labels, even though I have specified only distinct data to be shown in the `SqlCommand` query. I apologize if I am not explaining correctly but any help or direction will be much appreciated.

Results when searching a specific state:

```
BOID: 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205,   
BEX: 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205, 9205,    
NPA: 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205,    
NXX: 212, 214, 226, 238, 244, 250, 251, 252, 254, 262, 263, 278, 279, 290, 298, 307, 313, 314, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 326, 328, 380, 397, 402, 403, 408, 414, 421, 423, 437, 444, 445, 453, 458, 502, 520, 533, 536, 545, 558, 583, 591, 592, 595, 599, 682, 714, 731, 733, 776, 780, 781, 783, 786, 787, 788, 791, 798, 801, 802, 803, 808, 822, 823, 824, 833, 836, 841, 854, 856, 868, 870, 871, 873, 876, 879, 913, 916, 917, 923, 925, 929, 930, 933, 939, 940, 941, 942, 943, 945, 949, 951, 956, 957, 967, 968, 969, 970, 972, 977, 978, 979, 980, 981, 982, 983, 985, 987, 988, 989, 991, 995,
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a GROUP BY clause in your SQL SELECT statement?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I have not tried the GROUP BY clause yet, I will look into that.
This is a small internal tool being used by me at work so I am not worried about injections at the moment, thank you though!

Comment: GROUP BY without any aggregates is actually the same as DISTINCT.  This is essentially how distinct is suposed to work - in the presented case you are getting a row for every distinct value of NXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a query with distinct, it will give you the distinct combination of all the selected columns. to accomplish what you want, it would have to be more like this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select distinct State from TAS where StateId=" + "'" + State + "'" + " AND City=" + "'" + City + "'", con);
...code to collate all the unique values and add to appropriate label...

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select distinct City from TAS where StateId=" + "'" + State + "'" + " AND City=" + "'" + City + "'", con);
...code to collate all the unique values and add to appropriate label...

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select distinct Exchange from TAS where StateId=" + "'" + State + "'" + " AND City=" + "'" + City + "'", con);
...code to collate all the unique values and add to appropriate label...
```

etc.

There are many other ways to accomplish the same thing as well

For the repeating the multiple queries, you can use something roughly like this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand..the query for getting unique state
con.Open();
using ( SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while (rdr.Read())
      {
          this.STATE.Text = rdr["State"].ToString();
       }
    }
```

then repeating the others

Comment: I will give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: It seems it does not like that I am opening multiple SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); running at the same time. I have separated the SqlCommands and updated the variables but tells me that the original reader needs to be closed, however simply stating rdr.Close(); doesn't work either.

Comment: do it like this

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand..the query for getting unique state
    con.Open();
   using ( SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
        while (rdr.Read())
          {
              this.STATE.Text = rdr["State"].ToString();
           }
        }

then repeat that for the next city, exchange type, etc

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you replace the += with = ?

Comment: It will only show only value in each field and not show any other unique values,
 BOID: 205, BEX: 9205, NPA: 205, NXX: 995,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for some reason you can't afford to make multiple queries to the DB, and that your result data set is  small. This might be faster if your server round trip is long or your DBA will hate you for spamming him with 6 table scans etc.
You could perform the actual distinct in your code.

```
        con.Open();
        var hsNxx = new HashSet<int>();
        var hsBex = new HashSet<int>();
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {


            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                hsBex.Add((int)rdr["Bex"]);
                hsNxx.Add((int)rdr["Nxx"]);

            }

        }

        con.Close();
        string distinctBex =hsBex.Count == 1 ? hsBex.First().ToString() : hsBex.Select(f => f.ToString()).Aggregate((x, y) => x + "," + y);
        this.BEX.Text = distinctBex;
```

Assumed the columns are ints. 
You could also implement the Text to be changed only once and not mutated every row with +=

As a side note I recommend warpping IDisposables of connection/reader/command in a using clause